# Javascript Selecting one line at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a feature or a way to select on line at a time from jquery/javascript. The issues is that it must be the element inside a `<pre></pre>` tags.

The code look like this

```
Course        Grade Mark
Science       70    50
```

I would like to preserver the space, and I believe that selecting one line at time would be great.

Here a look at what i have, not much

```
var test = $('pre').html();
```

Thank you.
For any input.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully... Do you want to select all the elements and then loop through them one by one? Could you show what you've tried? a jsFiddle?

Comment: I only want to select the element <pre></pre> and then select one line at the time inside. the pre code. Update with a preview, maybe if i add html(0) and count would this work?

Comment: You mean selecting line by line.

Comment: Yeah, that what i mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split on \n :

```
var lines = $("pre").text().split("\n");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9XscN/

Comment: I think that what i am actually looking, thanks i will accept this answer, thank you very much